# Cloning git repository Failure

Tags: git, url, git-clone

When i try to clone following from repository:

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5
```

i'm getting this error:

```
fatal: Unable to look up gitorious.org (port 9418) (This is usually a temporary error         during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. )
```

**What's the problem?**

another thing that my network use proxy and i have already set it:

```
 git config --global http.proxy http://192.168.0.7:8080
```

Comment: Works for me. Also why is it tagged [tag:github]?

Comment: If you go through a proxy, chances are that you are not allowed to make connections to the outside world without going through the proxy and that this proxy only supports HTTP/HTTPS requests (not GIT). So you should probably use the url: `https://git.gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's because of setting proxy, because i already test it in another place without proxy server and it works, so what is the right way to set proxy for git?!

Comment: try this `git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try first with an https address, rather than the git one (which needs a special port)

```
https://git.gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git
```

The alternative can be complex (like [ssh port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711946/6309))