# git protocol fails on SSH tunnel

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

For some reason, I can not access following remote git repository (git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git) from my local host A. I have another remote host B, which can access the above repository. SSH server on host B is started.

Following steps are based on [how-to-use-ssh-tunnel-to-forward-git-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711812/how-to-use-ssh-tunnel-to-forward-git-protocol):

1. config git proxy:

   > ```
   > git config --glocal core.gitproxy ck-gitproxy
   > ```
2. ck-gitproxy script is:

   > ```
   > PROXY=127.0.0.1 
   > DEBUG="-d -d -d -d" 
   > exec socat $DEBUG STDIO SOCKS4:${PROXY}:$1:$2
   > ```
3. On local host A, I open a SSH tunnel:

   > ```
   > ssh -L 9418:git.linphone.org:9418 <host-B-IP>
   > ```
4. Then i tried to clone the repository from host A. But both following commands fail:

> ```
> git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git
> git clone git://localhost/linphone-android.git
> ```

error message:

```
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] N opening connection to AF=2 127.0.0.1:1080
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] N opening connection to git.linphone.org:9418 via socks4 server 127.0.0.1:1080 as user "mancook"
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D getaddrinfo("git.linphone.org", NULL, {1,2,1,6,0,(nil),(nil),(nil)}, 0xbffb3708)
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D getaddrinfo(,,,{{AF=2 94.23.19.176:0, }) -> 0
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D socket(2, 1, 6)
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 3
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D fcntl(3, 2, 1)
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D fcntl() -> 0
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D connect(3, {2,AF=2 127.0.0.1:1080}, 16)
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D connect() -> -1
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D getsockname(3, 0xbffb36ec, 0xbffb35e8{112})
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D getsockname(, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:41759}, {16}) -> 0
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] E connect(3, AF=2 127.0.0.1:1080, 16): Connection refused
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] N exit(1)
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] I shutdown(3, 2)
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] D shutdown()  -> -1
2015/03/15 13:17:41 socat[3496] I shutdown(3, 2): Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I googled this question for the whole day, but fails to find the solution! Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git
```

just now on its own and it worked, without any extra setup. Maybe you're overcomplicating things?

Comment: I am in china. It is very very slow! I started the clone job last night, and it is still running.... So the tunnel is necessary for me!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. 
I fix this problem with a VPN client.